# How to add Spark Java API (Javadoc) in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark

I want to add Spark Java API (Javadoc) in my eclipse so that when I hover mouse on the classes/methods/objects from Spark API , I get to see the documentation about the class or method. I want to know from where I will be able to get it. I searched a lot and this is the closest I have been to. I want to access [this documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) from my eclipse.

Comment: Within eclipse you can paste the javadoc location in the properties of a referenced library

Comment: @Gilfoy Yes , That I know, but I want Java Spark API for download, and then I can give the path where I have downloaded. Do you know from where I can download that ?

Comment: So you want to know where you can get the spark Api jar from? I downloaded a pre-built binary tgz from the apache spark website (for hadoop 2.6). In it is a lib folder with a file called spark-assembly-1.6.1hadoop2.6.0.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1. download spark-core: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/1.0.0/spark-core_2.10-1.0.0.jar
2. Right click your project -> Build -> Configure build path
3. Add the downloaded .jar via "Add External JARs" and press OK.
4. Then, expand the spark-core.jar item (black arrow left from spark-core)
5. Edit the Javadoc location to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java
6. Apply -> Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these simple steps :

1. Download this jar file  **org.apache.spark.api**
2. Right click on eclipse's project -> Build -> Configure build path
3. Select Java build path -> choose Libraries -> Add External jar
4. Select  **org.apache.spark.api**  And then **OK**

Now check,Spark api is add in your project.

I think it will work.

Comment: Can you add a link from where I can download org.apache.spark.api ? 
I found one , I downloaded, tried the steps you mentioned. It didn't work